# Free camera Y position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made my camera a child of my character so that it follows it's movement. However I don't want the camera to move upwards when the player jumps, or follow it when it falls.

Is there a way in c# i can free the y?

Comment: Please show previous work (or attempts) before asking a question like this. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just position to camera using C# rather than making it a child transform. If you've attempted this but failed, please share that code so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to update your camera position manually and store Y position of a camera after initialization.

```
Transform playerTransform;
float yPosition;
Vector3 offsetVector; // some offset vector from player

public void AttachToPlayer(Transform pTransform) {
    playerTransform = pTransform;
    y.position = playerTransform.position.y + 0.5; //some offset 
}

void Update() {
 transform.position = playerTransform.position + playerTransorm.rotation*offsetVector;
 transform.position.y = yPosition;
}
```

That should do the trick, but it is very simple implementation. And it will only work if level is on same y position.